# How to declare variable of type A or B when one extends the other in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-typescript

I have a context provider which streams user data throughout the app.

I have a Student interface:

```js
export interface Student extends User
```

I would like the provider to return user data of type `Student` or `User` as follows:

```js
let userData: Student | User = null;
```

When trying to access a property only available to students, `userData?.currentTeam`, VS Code throws the following error:

```
Property 'currentTeam' does not exist on type 'Student | User'.
  Property 'currentTeam' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)
```

**I need help finding out why it is defaulting to the parent interface and how to allow the option of both.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior of unions: unless you do something to check what type you're dealing with, typescript will only allow you to access properties that exist on *all* members of the union.

Here are some examples of how you can narrow down the type. You can check if the property exists:

```
if ('currentTeam' in userData) {
  console.log(userData.currentTeam);
}
```

Or if you've created classes (which you may not have), you can use instance of:

```
if (userData instanceof Student) {
  console.log(userData.currentTeam);
}
```

Or, you can change the types so they all have a property in common, which you can then check to see what type you're dealing with. This is sometimes called a "discriminated union".

```
interface User {
  type: 'user',
  // rest of the type here
}

interface Student extends User {
  type: 'student',
  currentTeam: // something,
  // rest of the type here
}

if (userData.type === 'student') {
  console.log(userData.currentTeam);
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I was able to use this to set the default value on the form field with the ternary:
`'currentTeam' in userData ? userData.currentTeam.teamName: 'No Team Set'`